# Cannot set the CanUserAddRows property of the DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, controls

I have a `DataGrid` in a WPF Window like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="True" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="True" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="X"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I go to the properties panel of the `DataGrid` and try to check the `CanUserAddRows` property, it remains unchecked! however it adds the `CanUserAddRows="True"` to the XAML. Same things happens with the `CanUserDeleteRows` property.

What is going on?

Comment: Probably the collection is of interface/abstract type, or something else that cannot be constructed deterministically on the fly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if I understand the question correctly: even though you set the `CanUserAddRows="True"` property in XAML, when you check in the code behind, the same property is `False`.

It's likely that you are binding to a read-only collection of some kind. Make sure you are binding to something like `ObservableCollection<T>` to make these features work.

If there is no source specified at all, the `DataGrid` won't be able to create new rows into it.

Comment: I haven't bind it to anything. I'm going to add the data simply in code. But I'm not sure if it is possible or not!

Comment: that's the problem then, if the `DataGrid` does not have a source, it won't be able to create new rows into it. Think of it as *items.Add(new Item());* but where items is `NULL`

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to add some x, y data which are filled in two textboxes. When I click a button I want those (x,y) data be added to the datagrid. what is the best way of doing it?